# facial recognition using opencv 3.1.0 on raspberry pi3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, raspbian-wheezy

I am using opencv 3.1.0, python on raspberry pi 3 for facial recoginition and I used the code below but I am getting an error please how do I fix this I have followed numerous sites on how to fix it but none of them worked

### ERROR

```
recognizer= cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()

AttributeError: module ‘cv2’ has no attribute
```

### CODE

```
import cv2,os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

recognizer = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
detector= cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

def getImagesAndLabels(path):
    #get the path of all the files in the folder
    imagePaths=[os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)] 
    #create empth face list
    faceSamples=[]
    #create empty ID list
    Ids=[]
    #now looping through all the image paths and loading the Ids and the images
    for imagePath in imagePaths:
        #loading the image and converting it to gray scale
        pilImage=Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')
        #Now we are converting the PIL image into numpy array
        imageNp=np.array(pilImage,'uint8')
        #getting the Id from the image
        Id=int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
        # extract the face from the training image sample
        faces=detector.detectMultiScale(imageNp)
        #If a face is there then append that in the list as well as Id of it
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            faceSamples.append(imageNp[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            Ids.append(Id)
    return faceSamples,Ids

faces,Ids = getImagesAndLabels('dataSet')
recognizer.train(faces, np.array(Ids))
recognizer.save('trainner/trainner.yml')
```

Comment: I used the following tutorial for facial recognition: https://www.hackster.io/gr1m/raspberry-pi-facial-recognition-16e34e

Comment: @PedroLobito I don't understand the concept of AWS Rekognition and I am using this facial recognition concept http://thecodacus.com/face-recognition-opencv-train-recognizer/#.WQ7iuVKZO8U

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you are new, please spend some time to read [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Started from `OpenCV 3`, `cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()` has been moved under `cv2.face` module as `cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()`. The `AttributeError` above just said `opencv` can't find the module.

The `cv2.face` module is now moved to `opencv_contrib` modules. You need to build the `opencv`[[1]](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) with `opencv_contrib`[[2]](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) from source if you can't find a suitable `raspbian` or `debian` based binary.